# how the child in this program will run?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, fork, wait

I don't fully understand the fork function,i don't get how the father and child process contineo from fork() function or the skip this line and go to the next one. for example:

```
int value = 0;
if (fork()!=0)
{
 wait(&value);
 value = WEXITSTATUS(value);
 value++;
}
printf("%d\n",value);
value+=2;
exit(value);
```

when we implement the fork function the father go for wait() function but what i don't understand that from where the child start to run from the if() or he escape it and go immediately for the printf?
Thanks for helping :)

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: i didn't actually i just try to understand fork and what will happen in this function

Comment: Why did you not try it?  Running it would have demonstrated its operation.

Comment: i'm learning Operation System and i'm new to all this so i don't know how to do it. i think i need linux which  i don't have :/

Comment: if you are learning operation system then first think you should do is set up a linux system or a vm in windows first. I highly advice you to run the program first and use gdb and debug the program you wrote.

Comment: One process calls `fork`, but it returns in each of two processes.

Comment: I don't understand - if you don't have the OS and/or source code that you built and tested.....  where did the code come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole program is duplicated and both father and son start from `fork()`
The father enter inside the `if` because its fork return value is non null, and after go to

```
printf("%d\n",value);
value+=2;
exit(value);
```

while the son just go to this line, because is pid is zero.

The son exits 2 because of line `value += 2`.

The father waits for that value (ie value = 2), increment it (value = 3), and then add 2 (value = 5).

Comment: if i understand right that mean if child and father process works then the output will be: 0 and then 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

`fork()` basically [makes a copy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) of the process calling it.

That means the runtime state of that process when it called `fork()`, including the current instruction pointer. The main difference between the parent and the child process is that the new copy of the old process is modified so that the return value from `fork()` will return `0` while for the old process it returns a PID.

Except for that, the child will be in the same state as the parent and continue execution from the same point as the parent, i.e. the call to `fork()`.